# Bit operation filter with length consideration

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need to write a function that get 2 bytes and a boolean:

```
filter(int length, uint16_t* A, uint16_t* B, bool checkByZeros)
```

the needed logic is: 
length is the number of *bits* to check (i.e. if length = 9 the byte array will contain 2 bytes)
if checkByZeros is `False`

the function will return `true` if:

```
all the bytes set (=1) in A are also set in B
```

in example (length=9):

```
checkByZeros=True, A:000001111, B:000001111 ==> True
checkByZeros=True, A:000001111, B:000011111 ==> True
checkByZeros=True, A:000001111, B:000000111 ==> False
```

if checkByZeros is `False`

the function will return `true` if:
all the bytes not-set (=0) in A are also not-set in B
in example:

```
checkByZeros=False, A:000001111, B:000001111 ==> True
checkByZeros=False, A:000001111, B:000011111 ==> False
checkByZeros=False, A:000001111, B:000000111 ==> True
```

The implementation is quite naiive if i loop over the byte bit by bit but I need a faster bit operation metod.
Any suggestions? I'm kinda lost because when considering different length the bit operations should ignore bits that are located after lenght

Comment: Do you code in `c` or `c++`? These are different languages, and neither one has the built-in type `byte`

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I'm on c++ and currently instead of byte[] I use uint16_t so length max value is 16, but soon I will change the implementation to use **uint8_t *array** anyways AFAIK the bit operation can be done on any type

Comment: How much do you know about [the bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)? It seems that for the first case (when `checkByZeros == true`) then simple masking and comparison for equality should be enough (`A & B == A`). The same method could be used for the second case as well (with the help of the bitwise complement operator).

Comment: Please check your question again; your use of `checkByZeros` is not consistent across post, for example, *"if checkByZeros is `False`"* is used twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bitwise operators to check multiple bits simultaneously. For example, if you want to check that all set bits of `a` have corresponding set bits of `b`, you could write the following:

```
(~b & a & mask) == 0
```

Here `~b` is a bitwise inversion of `b`, which has `1`s on all places where `b` has `0`s, so, `~b & a` will have `1` in some position if and only if `a` has `1` in this position and `b` has `0`, which is exactly what we need.

The mask is `(1 << length) - 1`, that is, contains `1` in `length` lowest bits only, and thus helps us ignore the highest bits of result, which we don't want to check.

This method allows you to check up to 64 bits (length of `long long`) at once. If `checkByZeros` is `true`, you can write a similar code.

Comment: what is the code in the case of check by zero = true? do the same without the ~b??

Comment: `b & ~a & mask`, logic is exactly the same as in the first case

Answer (score 0):

```
uint16_t temp;

if(checkByZeroes)
{
    temp = *B | *A; // ignore 0's in B which are not in a
}
else
{
    temp = *B & *A; // ignore 1's in B which are not in a
}

return temp == *A;
```

Comment: What about the length?

Comment: I offered this assuming the bits at the left of the length will always be zero. If that's the case, those bits wont affect the result. Else, you need a mask as alexeskuzmin0 said.

Comment: I wish I could upvoat you @t.m.